# XQuery/XPath: Element id gets lost in output

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsd, xquery

I will give an example to better explain myself:

I want to display all product with a selling price value with at least 20% lower than the listing price and it has to be the same product ean to compare the prices. At the end the shop id with its product ean, selling price and listing price gets displayed.

```
<company>
    <products>
        <product ean="111">
            <listingPrice>100</listingPrice>
        </product>
        <product ean="222">
            <listingPrice>500</listPrice>
        </product>
        <product ean="333">
            <listingPrice>1000</listingPrice>
        </product>
    </products>
    <shops>
       <shop id="1">
        <collection>
         <product>
           <ean>111</ean>
           <sellingPrice>90</sellingPrice>      
         </product>
        </collection>
       </shop>

       <shop id="2">
         <collection>
         <product>
           <ean>888</ean>
           <sellingPrice>10</sellingPrice>      
        </product>
         <product>
           <ean>222</ean>
           <sellingPrice>300</sellingPrice>     
        </product>
       </collection>
       </shop>

        <shop id="3">
         <collection>
         <product>
           <ean>222</ean>
           <sellingPrice>600</sellingPrice>     
        </product>
        </collection>
       </shop>


       <shop id="4">
         <collection>
         <product>
           <ean>111</ean>
           <sellingPrice>20</sellingPrice>      
        </product>

         <product>
           <ean>333</ean>
           <sellingPrice>140</sellingPrice>     
        </product>
        </collection>

       </shop>
   </shops>
</company>
```

XQuery:

```
declare variable $factor as xs:decimal external := 0.8;

declare function local:listing-price($product as element(product)) as xs:decimal?
{
    root($product)/company/products/product[@ean = $product/ean]/listingPrice
};

declare function local:check-price($product as element(product), $factor as xs:decimal) as xs:boolean
{
    $product/sellingPrice < local:listing-price($product) * $factor
};


doc('shop.xml')/company/shops/shop/collection[product[local:check-price(., $factor)]] 
!
<shop id="{@id}">{
    product[local:check-price(., $factor)] 
    ! 
    <product ean="{ean}" sellingPrice="{sellingPrice}" listingPrice="{local:listing-price(.)}" />
}</shop>
```

Solution would be:

```
<shop id="2">
     <product ean="222" sellingPrice="300" listingPrice="500"/>
  </shop>

  <shop id="4">
     <product ean="111" sellingPrice="20" listingPrice="100"/>
     <product ean="333" sellingPrice="140" listingPrice="1000"/>
  </shop>
```

But I get this:

```
<shop id="">
     <product ean="222" sellingPrice="300" listingPrice="500"/>
  </shop>

  <shop id="">
     <product ean="111" sellingPrice="20" listingPrice="100"/>
     <product ean="333" sellingPrice="140" listingPrice="1000"/>
  </shop>
```

I don't know why I lose the shop id value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the expression `doc('shop.xml')/company/shops/shop/collection[product[local:check-price(., $factor)]]` you want to move the `collection` into the predicate: `doc('shop.xml')/company/shops/shop[collection/product[local:check-price(., $factor)]]`. That way the map operator `!` works on the `shop` element and then the expression constructing the new result `<shop id="{@id}">` will select the `id` attribute of the `shop`.

With your current attempt the `collection` element is the context item on the right hand side of the `!` operator and it doesn't have an `id` attribute.

Of course, once you have changed the context item for the outer expression to be a `shop` element, you have to adjust the inner expression from `product[local:check-price(., $factor)]` to `collection/product[local:check-price(., $factor)]`.

Comment: Ok thank you, I get the id now but I lose product ean, sellingPrice and listingPrice in the output. https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6y7/5

Comment: @Lyaso, see the edit, if the outer context item has changed, the inner expression will need to be adjusted as well.